# I am receiving an XML Error and do not know how to repair it

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

I am creating a Microsoft Flight Simulator 2020 folder structure for the SDK Developer allowing me to create sceneries. Some of these folders have XML files. This particular XML file is located in the root structure and identifies some essential features. It seems to work ok most times, but when I use the XML Tools Validator, it reports an error.
What do I need to add or change to remove the error?
I have supplied two pics of the code.
1 is the parent code supplied in the SDK
[parent code from sdk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnpSL.jpg)
2 is my version that keeps getting the error
enter image description here
[my code from parent example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoZze.jpg)

Comment: Please don't use snapshots but code in your post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The " mark before AYMK is incorrect - it is not the ASCII 22 character but a 'curve' quote. Overtype with a quote character on your keyboard.

This is a common problem when copying from a word processor file or some other source that likes to prettify quoted text.

Comment: Like using MS Word.

Comment: Thank you Phil. Spot on. I was looking at the code earlier and saw the dog ears looked a tad different before AYMK. It did not sink in the different " of course have a different code for the character than the other " in the line. When I use the plugins XML Tools, Validate now, I no longer get the error(Thankyou) but now asks to select XML schema(XDS) and Namespace URI. Is this important? as the XML seems to work now.